# AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: tensorflow

Estoy tratando de correr este repo https://github.com/MioChiu/TF_CenterNet
y me tira el siguiente error:

'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'decode'".
La linea en particular donde me tira error es en "line = line.decode()"

def process_data(line, use_aug):

```
if 'str' not in str(type(line)):
    print (line)
    line = line.decode()
s = line.split()
image_path = s[0]
if not os.path.exists(image_path):
    raise KeyError("%s does not exist ... " %image_path)
image = np.array(cv2.imread(image_path))
labels = np.array([list(map(lambda x: int(float(x)), box.split(','))) for box in s[1:]])

if use_aug:
    image, labels = random_horizontal_flip(image, labels)
    image, labels = random_crop(image, labels)
    image, labels = random_translate(image, labels)

image, labels = image_preporcess(np.copy(image), [cfg.input_image_h,cfg.input_image_w], np.copy(labels))

output_h = cfg.input_image_h//cfg.down_ratio
output_w = cfg.input_image_w//cfg.down_ratio
hm = np.zeros((output_h, output_w, cfg.num_classes),dtype=np.float32)
wh = np.zeros((cfg.max_objs, 2),dtype=np.float32)
reg = np.zeros((cfg.max_objs, 2),dtype=np.float32)
ind = np.zeros((cfg.max_objs),dtype=np.float32)
reg_mask = np.zeros((cfg.max_objs),dtype=np.float32)

for idx, label in enumerate(labels):
    bbox = label[:4]/cfg.down_ratio
    class_id = label[4]
    h, w = bbox[3] - bbox[1], bbox[2] - bbox[0]
    radius = gaussian_radius((math.ceil(h),math.ceil(w)))
    radius = max(0, int(radius))
    ct = np.array([(bbox[0] + bbox[2]) / 2, (bbox[1] + bbox[3]) / 2], dtype=np.float32)
    ct_int = ct.astype(np.int32)
    draw_umich_gaussian(hm[:,:,class_id], ct_int, radius)
    wh[idx] = 1. * w, 1. * h
    ind[idx] = ct_int[1] * output_w + ct_int[0]
    reg[idx] = ct - ct_int
    reg_mask[idx] = 1

return image, hm, wh, reg, reg_mask, ind
```

Comment: Traduce tu pregunta xD, translate your question

Comment: Estás en SO en español

Comment: estoy tratando de correr el código de https://github.com/MioChiu/TF_CenterNet  y me tira el error "AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'decode'".